# Python - try-except

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the Python try-except construct. It seems quite involved because it has optional `finally` and `else` clauses. Also, there may be `return`, `break`, `continue` involved there. You may decide to name or not the exception which you catch etc. etc...

Anyway, I think I understand well the flow of control now, but here is a quote from the Python docs which seems wrong to me.

> The following points discuss more complex cases when an exception occurs:
>
> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the exception may be handled by an except clause. In all cases, the exception is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.

The quote is from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

**Point 8.6**

That last sentence just doesn't seem right. What do they mean by that? Seems plain wrong. My tests show the exception is not re-raised if you catch it and handle it (of course). So... what does that note fromt the docs mean?

Could anyone explain please?

**EDIT:**
Seems someone fixed the doc page after I asked this question. Is that so?

Comment: See "A more complicated example:" a few lines down, it demonstrates this case.

Comment: @Barmar But this example is not "in all cases", it's only in the case when you didn't catch the right exception type.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the example carefully enough.

Comment: I suspect it should read "in all *other* cases".

Comment: @chepner Great minds think alike, I just write the same thing as a comment on the answer.

Comment: [Python Exceptions: An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/)

Comment: [This section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) of the docs explains this much better I think. It talks through how `finally` works a couple paragraphs down.

Comment: Seems someone fixed the docs after I asked this question, is that so?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked it up because that seemed strange to me, too. I think the wording is very bad there. You are totally correct, an exception does not get re-raised if it is handled inside the `except` block.

They were referring to cases where such an exception does not get caught:

> As you can see, the finally clause is executed in any event. The
>   TypeError raised by dividing two strings is not handled by the except
>   clause and therefore re-raised after the finally clause has been
>   executed.

This is from [the same example you posted](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html), just a few lines further below.

So, to sum it up. The docs should probably say:

> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the
>   exception may be handled by an except clause. In all cases, an
>   exception is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed, *if it has not been caught in one of the except blocks*.

and as it was pointed out in the discussion, this seems to the intended wording:

> If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the
>   exception may be handled by an except clause. In all other cases, an
>   exception is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.

Comment: This answer needs some work. You can't catch or handle the exception in a `finally` clause.

Comment: They probably meant to write "in all *other* cases"

Comment: @Barmar Oh, maybe... If "all other cases" was written it would make sense.

Comment: What about this: "If the `try` statement reaches a `break`, `continue` or `return` statement, the `finally` clause will execute just prior to the `break`, `continue` or `return` statement’s execution." >>> OK, `return` I get but... But what do `break` and `continue` have to do with try-except construct? I guess they meant in the case when try-except is embedded inside a loop, right?

Comment: yeah but continue/break are implying that since they are reserved words with an assigned meaning and context, so I think that wording is okay

Comment: No... one can imagine the opposite scenario too: a loop inside a try block (e.g. that's what first came to my mind). Then this sentence does not make much sense either. Does it? I think it is confusing to say the least. They state it as a general truth but it refers to some specific scenario. No?

Comment: `break` and `continue` can occur in any part of a `try`/`except` statement, just as they can appear in an `if` statement, as long as the `try`/`except` occurs lexically in a loop.